# How do I go from Ubuntu 14.04 to Windows?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I bought a Dell laptop used, and it had Ubuntu 14.04 on it, but I prefer Windows. I noticed that there was a sticker on the corner of my laptop that said "Windows Vista Basic" and another one that says, "Intel Core 2 Duo inside". I would like to switch back to Windows, but I don't know how. Also, I am not able to use a disc to switch because the disc drive doesn't work.

Comment: Short answer is "just install Windows" as if there was no Ubuntu installed. How to do it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

First, try to determine if you have Windows still on that laptop. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and run `blkid`. If you see an entry there that has `TYPE="ntfs"`, then you've still got windows on that laptop. If you don't--the only option is to install windows after having purchased a license and appropriate method of installation--usb or cd.

If you have an ntfs entry, then reboot the laptop, when the system starts up, hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key and you should enter the OS selection screen (commonly known as `grub`). There you will find an entry for Windows.

Chances are you're gonna need to reset windows password. If that's the case, use one of the recovery tools. My personal favorite is Trinity Rescue. I keep it on a cd (for those lovely moments when i forget my windows password), but you can use usb as well.

Good luck !